# Click on a button in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, onclick

I'm new in Webscraping, I want to click this button "Afficher plus" which has the HTML code below.

```
<button class="more-results js-more-results" id="search-more-results">Afficher plus de résultats</button>
```

I tried the code below in selenium but it doesn't click the button.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari() 
driver.get(carte)
bt = driver.find_element_by_id("search-more-results")
bt.click()
```

"carte" is the link the of web page I want to **scrape**.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

1 Check if this button is not inside an iframe.

2 If not, try waiting until this button is clickable

3 '"carte" is the link the of web page I wanna to **scrape**.' You are using get() function incorrectly. It is used to open a page, not to get a link from a page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari() 
driver.get("YOUR WEB PAGE")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "search-more-results")))
bt = driver.find_element_by_id("search-more-results")
bt.click()
```

If this won't work, try CSS selector or XPath. Example for CSS:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-more-results")))
email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#search-more-results').click()
```

Comment: hi I finale discover that I should add.  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", bt) to click the button because it need to excuse a script. Thank you